# Top 3 and the sum of the rest in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, union, window-functions

Suppose I get the following result for a `GROUP BY` query on a table:

```
Name         Count(*)
Apple        6
Mango        3
Grape        8
Pomegranate  1
Strawberry   13
```

How can I get the top three elements listed and the rest of the elements summed up in some name like 'Others'. something like follows.

```
Name         Count(*)
Strawberry   13
Grape        8
Apple        6
Others       4
```

This is to be done in Oracle. Seaching yields results using `TOP` which is not available in Oracle.

Comment: You should use [UNION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't show any effort

Comment: It's a very nice and educative problem whose solution is helpful for the community.

Comment: It's true that the OP didn't post any SQL statements that he tried, but it does not follow that he didn't show any effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete solution including [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7838f/3):

```
WITH fruit_summary AS (
  SELECT fruit, cnt,
     RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS cnt_rank
  FROM (
    SELECT fruit, count(*) AS cnt
    FROM fruit_table
    GROUP BY fruit
  )
)
SELECT fruit, cnt
FROM (
  SELECT fruit, cnt, cnt AS val
  FROM fruit_summary
  WHERE cnt_rank <= 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Others', SUM(cnt), -1
  FROM fruit_summary
  WHERE cnt_rank > 3
)
ORDER BY val DESC
```

Note that the query can return more than 4 (3 + 1) rows if you have several summary lines with the same count in the top 3.

The WITH clause groups the source table by fruit and assigns a rank to each row. The resulting intermediate table is then used to display the top 3 as well as to summarize the resulting one.

Comment: Note that your output does not match the OP's expected output - you're using `COUNT(*)` in your main query (`SELECT 'Others', COUNT(*) ...`) where you should be using `SUM(cnt)`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work for you. You can actually use aggregates in window functions:

```
WITH f1 AS (
    SELECT fruit_name, COUNT(*) AS fruit_cnt, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS fruit_rank
      FROM fruits
     GROUP BY fruit_name
)
SELECT fruit_name, fruit_cnt, fruit_rank
  FROM f1
 WHERE fruit_rank <= 3
 UNION
SELECT 'Others' AS fruit_name, SUM(fruit_cnt) AS fruit_cnt, MAX(fruit_rank) AS fruit_rank
  FROM f1
 WHERE fruit_rank > 3
 ORDER BY fruit_rank
```

[Please see SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b09d2/3)